# How to deploy MVC 4 application without killing the user's sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, iis-7, web-deployment

We have a MVC 4 application that is very critical, and every time we need to deploy a new patch, all users are disconnected, they lost their sessions. 
For example: If a user is creating a new order with a hundred items, this order is lost and cannot be retrieved.
How can I deploy the application to production server without an app restart? Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default asp.net store session is set to **InProc** mode, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default.

So if you use it there is no way to save user session. You can implement your custom mode or use sql server mode.

Also i would not recommend you store that data in session, i would better create table in database and store that data

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: or move session state to State server or SQL server

Comment: Thank you all for the explanations! I´ll do that, save the items on a table to rescue the data later.